# Using Parsoid with Auth Remoteuser Extension on XAMPP (Windows)

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-api, mediawiki-extensions, visual-editor, parsoid

I have been searching for the last week trying to find an answer on how to use Visual Editor/Parsoid and Auth Remoteuser extensions together.

I am getting the following error when trying to Create/Edit a page:

```
Error loading data from server: apierror-visualeditor-docserver-http: HTTP 500. Would you like to retry?
```

Current environment:

- OS: Windows Server 2012 RT
- XAMPP: v3.2.2
- PHP: v7.1.12
- SQL: MariaDB 10.1.29
- Apache: v2.4
- MediaWiki: 1.30.0

LocalSettings.php

```
$wgEnableWriteAPI = true;

wfLoadExtension( 'VisualEditor' );

$wgDefaultUserOptions['visualeditor-enable'] = 1;
$wgDefaultUserOptions['visualeditor-editor'] = "visualeditor";
$wgHiddenPrefs[] = 'visualeditor-enable';

$wgVirtualRestConfig['modules']['parsoid'] = array(
    'url' => 'http://localhost:8000',
    'domain' => 'localhost',
);
```

config.yaml

```
mwApis:
  uri: 'http://localhost/api.php'
  domain: 'localhost'
```

httpd.conf

```
<Directory "D:/Wiki/htdocs">
    Options None 
    AllowOverride All 
    Order allow,deny 
    Allow from all 

    AuthType SSPI 
    SSPIAuth On 
    SSPIAuthoritative On 
    SSPIOfferBasic On 
    SSPIOmitDomain On 
    Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

When I go to Parsoid server from my computer, it is working. http://xx.xxx.xx.xx:8000. If I disable the Auth Remoteuser extension, then Visual Editor works fine.

I tried forwarding the cookies as suggested in the Parsoid documentation and it doesn't work. This Wiki is not private.

When I add the following to the httpd.conf Visual Editor works:

```
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Satisfy Any
```

The only problem is then, it doesn't automatically log in the user using their Windows Credential.

Comment: Since you are authenticating the MediaWiki requests by something other than cookies, forwarding cookies does't help. You need to make sure that Parsoid requests contain whatever thing the authentication is based on. (This should not be an issue on a non-private wiki, so you probably misconfigured something. From your last paragraph, probably on the web server level.)

Comment: @Tgr I'm using simple NTLM authentication.How would I add the authentication information to Parsoid? From my understanding, it seems Parsoid is trying to authenticate anonymously which is getting rejected by MediaWiki. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not sure if you can do that without patching Parsoid. Configuring MediaWiki to always trust requests coming from Parsoid might be easier. You can do it with a second authentication extension (e.g. [NetworkAuth](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:NetworkAuth) although it is out of date) or you can configure your web server to identify those requests (e.g. based on IP) and set REMOTE_USER.

Answer (score 0):

might be a bit late, but I just had the same issue. Seems like [this](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Topic:Shoa9n6ucfqhn7gj) solves it.
Just comment the deprecated setting in php.ini 
error_reporting=E_ALL -> ;error_reporting=E_ALL

'error_reporting' key under section '[PHP]' causes the issue.